# HTTPS permalinks resulting in 404

Tags: permalinks, 404-error, https

Migrated the site from http to https.The homepage is working fine the but other page(archive,single,page) templates are resulting in 404.

Here are the steps while migrating.Could anyone please point out where I am going wrong?

- Changed site name and site url to https scheme.
- Then added the following htaccess rule.

  ```
     <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
         RewriteEngine on
         RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [NC]
         RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
     </IfModule>
  ```
- Flushed the rewrite rules with `flush_rewrite_rules()`.

The home and admin pages are fine but the single or the archive pages.This seems like the rewrite rules are not working with https scheme.

Could anyone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: "something is not working" is unlikely to get productive answers without giving as much details as you can. We don't have access to your server and telling you how to debug things is frankly too boring. start with you url structure, full htacces and what happens when you switch off plugins and use default theme.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30318921/1031689 worked for me

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`template_redirect`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/template_redirect) to force all the http traffic going through WordPress to use https:

```
function force_secure_navigation() {

    if ( ! is_ssl() ) :

        $url = 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

        wp_redirect( $url, 301 );

        exit();

    endif;

}

add_action( 'template_redirect', 'force_secure_navigation', 1 );
```

Remember that if you are working with https it's important to also serve your external resources, such as jQuery, Google Fonts or whatever is loading from a CDN, using https. You might want to check your `wp_enqueue_style` and `wp_enqueue_script` hooks to be sure there are no http calls left.

Comment: The template redirect does the same thing as a htaccess rule right?My redirection is working but its not picking up the right template.

Comment: With `template_redirect` you can access the queried object and use conditionals, such as `is_user_logged_in()`, `is_admin()`, etcetera. If you intend to redirect all the traffic to https then, yes, it's virtually the same but probably less performant.